# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel Auth

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, logout

**EDIT** : I am testing it now, so weird that sometimes it works and sometimes it gives me that error.

I have an application, I've override the logout function in Laravel so I have this in my `AuthController.php`

```
public function getLogout()
{

    $userid = Auth::user()->id;

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei');

    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $logHour = new LoginHour();
    $checkLogin = $logHour->checkLoginHoursOut(intval($userid), $today);

    if($checkLogin != null)
    {
        $loginhours = '';
        $timestamp = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $timestamp2 = strtotime($timestamp);

        $userLastLogin = $checkLogin[0]->timestamp;
        $userLastLogin2 = strtotime($userLastLogin);

        // Get difference in hours
        $diffHours = round(($timestamp2 - $userLastLogin2) / 3600, 2);


        LoginHour::where('date', '=', $today)->
                    where('user_id', '=', $userid)->
                    update(['loginhours' => $checkLogin[0]->loginhours + $diffHours, 'status' => 0, 'timestamp' => $timestamp]);
    }                    

    Auth::logout();

    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/auth/login');
}
```

But for some reason when I am trying to logout I have this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Which points me to this line

```
$userid = Auth::user()->id;
```

What could be the problem? I believe I could still access the Auth coz I'm not yet calling the `Auth::logout();` before that line?

Comment: Your always authenticated when you access it?

Comment: @Jeemusu What I do is login then logout, I dunno how come I became not authenticated when I just logged in successfully then trying to logout gives that error.

Comment: Try accessing the Auth::user() on other authenticated routes to debug it. May be worth applying a middleware to your logout route so it can't be accessed by unauthorised users.

Comment: What is `$this->redirectAfterLogout` set to ?

Comment: Have you applied the "auth" middleware to this function. Just asking cause you have made this 1 explicitly.

Comment: Guys, just an update, I've added Auth::check() on top then when I tried to logout the Auth check passes, but problem now is when I logout it just redirects me to /home without logging out? $this->redirectAfterLogout is set to /auth/login as seen in my code above.

Comment: ..the value of `this->redirectAfterLogout` it isn't shown in your code above. I'm assuming it isn't set on this controller so it's using `/auth/login` as the fallback?

Comment: @Jeemusu how to I set it? I thought this it the one to set it, return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/auth/login');

Comment: @JoeneFloresca The redirect after logout is hard coded in the trait `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`. You can override it by setting it at the top of your controller. `protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/auth/login';`.

Comment: @Jeemusu I have done that but seems now working, you have any idea why when I logout it just refirect me to /home? Without logging out?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem exists when you visit the `logout` route, without a logged in user.

So, you should check it at the top.

```
public function getLogout()
{
     if (Auth::guest()) return;

     ...
}
```

Comment: How is possible that I visit the logout route without a logged user if I login and then logout and have the error?